# Config host and open with webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

My question is very basic. I set the dev server like this in my webpack config:

```
devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 4002,
    overlay: true,
    open: true
}
```

I add the *host: '0.0.0.0'* in order to access the server via my IP address.
And it works fine with

> localhost:4002

**OR**

> < IP_ADDRESS >:4002

The problem is that with the *open: true* it opens the page in the browser with the hostname:

> 0.0.0.0:4002

and it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with [openPage option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveropenpage) which specifies the URL I want to open. The open option just tries to infer the URL you want using the host option.

```
devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 4002,
    overlay: true,
    open: true,
    openPage: 'http://localhost:4002'
}
```